# Django-like queries in Java/JPA

Tags: java, orm, jpa

Is there any library or framework to make JPA queries in a less verbose way such as:

```
User.query("age < 30")
```

instead of:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u FROM User u WHERE age < 30");
return query.getResultList();
```

I suppose there is no standard way to do it with JPA.  I've seen [Hibernate Criteria API](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/hibernatequery102/), that is not as simple as Django and forces your application to be coupled to Hibernate. I'd like to know what do you think about it and other approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a Java framework allow you to do that: Play! framework. It's a framework similar to Django but complety written using Java. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0.1/model

For instance you can write something like:

```
User.find("age< ?", 30).fetch();
```

Moreover this is not coupled to hibernate you can use other technologies like Google App Engine datastore or Amazon Simple DB throw [Siena](http://code.google.com/p/siena/)

Comment: Interesting. Some sections are experimental (SimpleDB) or seem to be under construction (Siena-remote).

Comment: One thing I don't like is the need to extend your domain classes from "siena.Model", because Java does not support multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your query shorter:

```
from User where age < 30
```

Additionally I would like to add that the Hibernate API is much more powerful and adds things like polymorphism and prefetching in a nice way, so don't give up on it yet.

Comment: Thank you. Any good link about Hibernate polymorphism and prefetching?

Comment: Look at the hibernate docs for HQL, 14.3 covers fetching and 14.8 polymorphic queries. 14.15 and 16 are good too.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling Did you mean "from User where age < 30" (in double quotes)?

Answer (score 1):

Related to it, I have also found that Spring Roo is able to generate entities following this "Active Record Pattern", and allows the developer to include finder methods.